# A functions question

Tags: functions, derivatives, solution-verification, proof-explanation

An all real function is defined as $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ where $f'(0)=a$ and $a$ is a constant. Prove that $f(x)=ax$.

What I've tried is the following:
Sub $x=0$
$f(0+y)=f(0)+f(y)$
$\therefore f(0)=0$, same result when $y=0$ is substituted
$\therefore$ at $(0,0)$ $f(0)=0$
$\frac{d}{dx}f(x+y)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}f(y)$
$\frac{d}{dx}f(x+y)=f'(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}f'(y)$
Sub $(0,0)$
$\frac{d}{dx}f(0)=f'(0)+\frac{dy}{dx}f'(0)$
$0=a+\frac{dy}{dx}a$
$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=-1$
But this doesn't get the desired answer when I integrate both sides, what have I done wrong? Am I even heading in the right direction?

New proof:
Keeping $y$ constant
$f'(x+y)=f'(x)$
Substituting $x=0$ gives $f'(y)=a$
$\therefore f(y)=ay+c$
Sub $y=0$
$c=f(0)$
To find $f(0)$:
Sub $x=0$ into original equation
$f(0+y)=f(0)+f(y)$
$\therefore f(0)=0$
$\therefore c=0$
$\therefore f(y)=ay$ which implies $f(x)=ax$

Comment: Why did you write that $f'(0)$ is constant? Do you know some function $f$ such that $f'(0)$ is *not* constant?

Comment: Just for clarity I guess

Answer (score 1):

One way is that, if you keep $y$ constant and differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, then you'll get $f'(x+y)=f'(x)$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Now substituting $x=0$ gives $f'(y) = a$ for all real $y$.

Another way is that for any real $x$ we have $$f'(x) = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(y)}{y}=a$$
where we use definition of derivative in first and last steps.

In both ways, then we get $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(x)dx=ax$ for all real $x$, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Does the new proof underneath now work?

Comment: The new proof is a copy of my first proof (except that you're using another part of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). Of course that works.

Answer (score 1):

After the step
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x+y)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}f(y)
$$
you make a mistake: the second summand is zero, not some $\frac{dy}{dx}f'(y)$.

However, there is an error even before that step: you cannot differentiate $f$ at a point $x$ if you don't prove the derivative exists at $x$, but you're only given that the function is differentiable at $0$.

What should you do, instead? Apply the definition of derivative:
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=f'(0)
$$
because you've already proved that $f(0)=0$.

Thus the function *is* everywhere differentiable and $f'(x)=a$ for every $x$. Hence $f(x)=ax$, with the fundamental theorem of calculus or by considering that the function $g(x)=f(x)-ax$ has everywhere zero derivative, so it is constant, and $g(0)=0$.